# why my video is not taking the full screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Yoga </title>
    <style>
        .video {
            filter:brightness(40%);
            width: 100%;
            height: 750px;
            object-fit: fill;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        @media (max-width:768px){
            .video {
            filter:brightness(40%);
            width: 100%;
            height: 650px;
            object-fit: fill;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <section  class="head">
        <video autoplay="true" loop="true" muted class="video">
            <source src="images/istockphoto-1305960252-640_adpp_is.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </source>
        </video>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

[why there is a gap between video and end of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT4dN.png)

there is a litter gap between the video and actual size of the window i want the video should have the full width and no white space anymore can anyone help me with this

Comment: 1. Your html is invalid. 2. Your body have default margin.

Comment: set initial margin to 0 `html,body {margin:0;}`

Comment: margins are part of the answer, but only part. What result do you actually want? If you want the video to fill the screen (but with no distortion) then you are looking for object-fit: cover. Some of the video image may be cut at the sides or at the top/bottom to make it fit. If you want the whole video to be visible then look at object-fit: contain, but there will be margins either at the sides or at the top bottom in most cases. Unless the aspect ratio of the video is the same as the aspect ratio of the viewport you have to make that decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of body element has margin: 8px default. add margin: 0; to body and it will works.